# how to display array element within check boxes - ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a simple issue , I am retrieving data from firebase into an array list . and i want to display  this array with check boxes. can you please help.
the list array (tasks) from firebase is ready , just trying to display it within check box.. 
the property 'checked ' is not exist in type 'event.target'

here is the ts code :

```
let currentUid=this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid.valueOf();
    this.items = afDB.list('ToDoList/'+currentUid).valueChanges();
    this.items.subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(""+ data);
      this.tasks = data;

checked($event){
    if(event.target.checked==true)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
  }
```

html code :

```
<ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let task of tasks">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="checked($event,task)"/>
```

Comment: show us your JSON structure. make sure you have some property to check the selection status. Eg.  [{name : "Sasuage", checked : true}]; try this sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio

Comment: checked(event,task){

    if(event.target.checked==true)
    {
         console.log(task);

      /*var delItems = this.afDB.list('ToDoList/'+this.currentUid);
         // Delete the file
      delItems.delete().then(function() {
        // File deleted successfully
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      });
*/
    }
    else
    {

    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, you just need to change the `change` event binding by `ionChange` (**[docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/#advanced)**) and handle the `$event` a little bit different.

Please take a look at the `HomePage` of this **[Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/handling-checked-event)** for a working demo.

### Component:

```
@Component({...})
export class HomePage {

  public tasks = [
    "Task 1",
    "Task 2",
    "Task 3"
  ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  checked(event: any, task: any){
    const isChecked = event.checked;

    // Here you can include your custom logic
    // to handle what happens when the checkbox
    // is checked or unchecked :)

    if(isChecked) {
      console.log(`The task ${task} is checked!`)

      // ...
      // ...
    } else {
      console.log(`The task ${task} is unchecked!`)

      // ...
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Please notice that the method receives both the `event` and the selected `task` and you can use `event.checked` to get the status of the checkbox.

### View:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <!-- ... -->

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let task of tasks">
      <ion-label>{{ task }}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="checked($event, task)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```